# track the data usage of each application

Tags: android

I found many functions which can track the entire data usage on android phone. But, is there any function which can track the data usage of each application?

Comment: I too searching for that.. But 3G watch Dog app , they displayed data usage by each app.

Answer (score 0):

open the dialer and dial: * # * # 4 6 3 6 # * # *

use the menu to get application usage statistics

you cannot do this from a program....